# Can I trigger a 'pull' update from a RoR app instead of 'push' from dev environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

Is it possible to trigger a server update via Capistrano on the actual deployment server, so it fetches updates rather than them being pushed to it?

Our customer's server config is locked down from external access, so can't push an update to it (but it can get to the interwebs, so could see a repository somewhere)

I can't believe I'm inventing something new here, so is it possible to visit and admin page in the app to find an update is available and stop/update/restart the server? What do other people do?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to manage app's status from within itself. You could have a separate app (not necessarily rails app, can be a couple of PHP scripts or whatever) that run `git pull` and friends upon your request.

Comment: Actually, when I was deploying with capistrano, that's exactly how it worked. I push to github, then capistrano ssh-es in and runs `git pull`. That's not your case?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - no, customer's server is locked down from external access, so can't push an update, can't even ssh into it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - why is managing app's status from within itself not a good idea?  Jenkins does it? - but that in itself is not a good reason to do it!

Comment: The trick would be to get someone at customer's site to trigger an update rather than making a visit myself...!  Via an 'admin' page (which they would have access to anyway) seemed simplest?

Comment: yeah, admin page, something like that.

Comment: "why is managing app's status from within itself not a good idea?" - what if you push a bad update and app refuses to boot? Or the admin interface is otherwise rendered inaccessible, because of some issue in the code? Separate page is more reliable, seems to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to finally close this off, we solved this eventually by moving the project tot `gitlab.com` and using a `gitlab-runner` to poll for deployments - thus, pulling updates, not having them pushed.